# Por que no se conecta mi componente con react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Tengo el siguiente componente en donde quiero recuperar información a través de una api, pero en el estado del componente no se está guardando las variables ni funciones que definí para recuperar dicha información. Tengo el siguiente error en consola:

[image: t]

'posts' y 'getPosts' son las variables y métodos respectivamente que se están perdiendo en mi componente.
Para los reducers tengo configurado de la siguiente manera:

Este es el store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
// import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState={};
const middleware=[thunk];
const store=createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
);
export default store;
```

Este es el index.js del reducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import Posts from './Posts';

export default combineReducers({
  Posts,
});
```

Este es el reducer de Posts

```
import {RECUPERAR_POSTS} from '../actions/types';
const initialState={
  posts: [],
};
export default function(state=initialState, action) {
  console.log(action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECUPERAR_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

}

Componente principal donde cargo al componente Lista, en el cual quiero mostrar la información recuperada de la api.

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
// import PrivateRoute from './common/PrivateRoute';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Menu} from './Layout/Menu';
import {Body} from './Layout/Body';
import {DetallePost} from './Posts/DetallePost';
import {cargarUsuario} from '../actions/auth';
import store from '../store';
import {Lista} from './Posts/Lista';

class Blog extends Component {
  // componentDidMount() {
  // store.dispatch(cargarUsuario());
  // }
  render() {
    console.log(store);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Menu/>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Lista}/>
          <Route exact path="/Detalle" component={DetallePost}/>
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Blog/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Componente Lista, el problema principalmente creo que está aqui, ya que ni la función para recuperar los datos que es getPosts ni la variable posts la cuál almacenaria los datos, ninguna se está conectado o enlazando con el componente.

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {getPosts} from '../../actions/posts';
export class Lista extends Component {
  static propTypes={
    posts:PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getPosts:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getPosts();
  }
  
  render() {
    const {posts}=this.props;
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      ....Resto de código jsx
     );
  };
};
const mapStateToProps=state=>({
  posts:state.posts,
});
// const mapStateToProps=state=>console.log(state)
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getPosts})(Lista);
```

Y aquí tengo mi función 'getPosts' donde hago el llamado a la api para recuperar la información.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {tokenConfig} from './auth';
import {RECUPERAR_POSTS} from './types';
// GET
export const getPosts=()=>(dispatch, getState)=>{
  axios.get('api/Post/', tokenConfig(getState))
      .then((res)=>{
     dispatch({
        type: RECUPERAR_POSTS,
        payload: res.data,
     });
      });
};
```

¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Parece que en tu ‘combineReducers’ está como ‘Posts’ y no como ‘posts’

Comment: @Isaac le cambíe a 'posts' pero sigo tieniendo el mismo error.

Comment: porque no usas `mapDispatchToProps` para usar las acciones? https://es.redux.js.org/docs/basico/uso-con-react.html#componentsappjs

Comment: @hawks pero al final no sería solo una función que me retornaría mi función ? Lo probaré de todas formas... y además ya lo había intentado así antes pero ahora no se xq no me funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu comentario te dejo la siguiente respuesta.

Nosé como lo has probado antes con `mapDispatchToProps` pero tal como tienes ahora la prop de `this.props.getPosts()` nunca desencadenará la llamada para recuperar los datos de tu api.

Me explico, la función `getPosts` es una función de orden superior(*High order function*), es decir, que devuelve otra nueva función, cuando haces `this.props.getPosts()` esto devuelve otra función que no se ejecuta y es la que se encarga de recuperar los datos y setearlos en el store.

Deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getPosts: () => dispatch(getPosts())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Lista);
```

Ahora si que se llamará a la api porque cuando hagas `this.props.getPosts()` esto ejecutará el `dispatch` y el `dispatch` recibe la función que devuelve `getPosts` osea la llamada a la api y internamente `redux-thunk` esperará a que se resuelva la función asíncrona y setear los nuevos datos en el store.

Espero que me haya explicado.

Comment: Si, muy clara tu explicación,gracias; ahora puedo entender mejor el funcionamiento, pero sin embargo sigue sin darme resultados,lo que me lleva a pensar que algo anda mal por detrás, asi que probaré con un nuevo proyecto desde 0, gracias una vez más.

Comment: de nada. Te recomiendo seguir el tutorial oficial de https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started para profundizar más.